# How to write an editable predefined string to cin input operator in a C++ console application

Tags: c++, cin, getline

My issue is in regards to outputting a predefined editable string to to the console window.

Take for example the following code snippet:

```
string data;
cout << endl << "Please enter new name: ";
getline(cin, data);
```

In the same input stream I want to write a predefined editable string, for example  "Michael Algrast" after "Please enter new name: " so that it is at the user's discretion to accept the default value by hitting enter, or modify it as required.

Please note that I'm aware of the carriage return character '\r' that takes me back to the beginning of the predefined string, and overwrites it, but that's not sufficient. I want to be able to move the cursor anywhere in the outputted predefined string and make changes anywhere I want.

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something very simple, or if this requires some form of user input emulation.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the features of the C++ Standard Library, you can't. The Standard Library is not intended to support interactive applications.

Comment: If this is purely a console app, you'll be limited. You could output the default value before asking for input, and if the user just hits enter, the returned string will be empty. If the string is empty, use the default.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate unfortunately that does not meet my requirements. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Xigma which OS is this for?

Comment: @ccpgh it is for Windows.

Comment: @Xigma ok. i added an answer below. I know of 'Curses' from Sun OS/Solaris. Looking at the wiki link below there are versions for Windows as well. It might be worth taking a look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using MS Visual Studio, and no GNU stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Curses to get the effect BUT it might entail a lot of work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)